# How to get multiplication sign in my answer (prime factorization)

Tags: c, primes, multiplication

I am making a program where the user enters a positive integer between 2 and 1000000, and if it is a prime number it prints "The number is a prime number" and if it isn't a prime number it prints the factorization of the number. I'm trying to put multiplication signs in between my factors, but can't figure it out! (ie: user inputs 24, program outputs 2 2 2 3, I want it to output 2x2x2x3). Any ideas? I have been trying for ages

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int N, a, divide, flag=0;
 printf("Please enter a positive integer ");
   scanf("%d",&N);
   if (N<2||N>1000000)
  {
    printf("Error!");
    return 0;
  }
  for(a=2;a<=N/2;++a)
 {
  if(N%a==0)
  {
      flag=1;
      break;
  }
 }
 if (flag==0)
  printf("The number %d is a prime number.", N);
 else
  {
     printf("The number %d is not a prime number.\nThe prime factors of %d are:",N, N);

divide = 2;

 while(N!=0&&flag==1){
    if(N%divide!=0)
        divide = divide + 1;
    else {
        N = N / divide;
        printf("%d",divide);
        if(N==1)
            break;
        }
    }
 }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem now? The extra `x`? So divide the loop such that it will treat the last iteration differently.

Comment: Its printing, but there is an extra `x`

Comment: `if(N==1)
            break;
        else printf("x");` instead of `if(N==1)
            break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you revers the problem, you need to print a "x" *before* your numbers, appart for the 1st one.

So just have a `int first=1;`. In the loop add:

```
if (first) {
  first = 0; // no more 1st loop
} else {
  printf("x"); // print a "x" before printing the next number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `printf`:

```
printf("%d%c", divide, (N > 1) ? 'x' : '\n');
```

which prints '\n' (carriage return) if you're on the last iteration, or 'x' if you're not.